How does the downwash behind a swept wing differ from a normal wing?
How does the downwash behind a swept wing differ from a normal wing?
(I know you can’t trust everything you see on the internet, but this seemed legitimate)
Here it said:

The downwash pattern on a swept wing tends to increase the AoA towards the wingtip. We normally think of downwash as being caused by wingtip vortices, but really, we can visualize the entire wing as being constructed of an infinite number of vortices that get rolled up into one big one behind the airplane, so there is downwash created all along the wing. When you add the effect of all these vortices together, you get a different lift pattern along the wing than you do with a straight wing.

How does the downwash pattern differ for a swept wing? What along the wing does this?
Basically, why does a swept wing have different downwash amounts at different points, while a straight wing doesn’t?
Also, the same source said that this varying downwash makes the swept wing tip stall.

The only reason that I can think of is because the wing gets thinner as you get to the tip, so the downwash decreases.
Actually, this isn’t probably true. The downwash behind a wing is due to the wing making lift. Another way to put it is that the lift changes the downwash amount, not that the downwash amount changes the lift.

We often approximate a wing with a bunch of horseshoe vortices located at the quarter chord.  In the most simple approximation, we only use one such vortex.
Think of the trailing vortices as a whole bunch of vortex segments that lead off to infinity.  Each one is just a short segment.
That vortex segment has strongest influence perpendicular to itself.  Its influence drops off greatly before and after the segment.
When you apply these horseshoe vortices to a straight wing, the trailing vortices all start at the same location and all trail off together.  So, their influence on the wing is all very similar.
When you apply these vortices to a swept wing, the inboard trailing vortices start first.  They are in-line with the wingtips and have greater influence on the lift of the wing.  The vortices that trail from the wing tips start later and do not have the same alignment with the center of the wing in order to have an effect.
This causes a swept wing to have a substantially different lift distribution than a straight wing.
Usually a swept wing will be twisted to adjust the lift distribution to avoid any serious problems with stall etc.
Edit: Add image of swept wing horseshoe vortex system.


I see. So what effect does the bound vortex have? The bound vortex doesn’t actually exist if I’m correct. In other words, what flow changes direction because of the bound vortex?

(From what I remember it's just the circulation around the wing, but I could be wrong)

Everything effects everything.  Yes the bound vortex is a primary driver of the downwash, but the bound vortex does not have uniform strength.  The strength of the bound vortex is determined by the solution to the whole flow field.  (This is a case where my answer is leaning heavily on the mathematical abstractions we would use to model this wing -- it is a case where you solving a homework problem in a textbook would go a long way).

I think I understand it a bit more now. So if the trailing vortices of a horseshoe vortex system are caused by the circulation around the wing, why would there be a trailing vortex near the wing root? There is no tip circulation or voticity there, right?

Vorticity is shed anywhere lift is produced.  So there certainly is vorticity at the root.  I've added an image above -- the image isn't great, the 3D rotation provides a strange perspective.  Each horseshoe vortex has three legs, the bound leg and two trailing legs.  All three legs of a given vortex have the same strength.  Where there are two adjacent trailing vortices, they have opposite direction and they partially cancel -- which goes to show that the local wake strength is related to the change in circulation across the wing.

I see. So the bound vortex at the tip has less of an effect because the one at the center/root has the effect of effecting the ones around it? Like the tip has no bound vortex beside it, because it is at the tip. This would change the pressure distribution of the wing. Also, I'm assuming the pressure distribution would be so that the pressure would be higher on the upper surface towards the tip (compared to the root), and if that's the case wouldn't that help the tip stall later than the root? (Lower pressure on upper surface will help stalls form)

To make more sense, the bound vortex close to the center of the wing has the bound vortex beside it, and then that one has a bound vortex beside it, etc etc. These all influence each other. When you get to the tipward bound vortex, there is no bound vortex beside it, so it changes the pressure distribution.

No, Look at the region perpendicular to the tip bound vortex -- notice that it only includes other trailing vortices and the opposite tip.  Next, look at the region perpendicular to the bound vortex trailing from the root -- notice that it includes much of the wing as well as all the other trailing vortices.  The original question was about swept wings -- if the wing was not swept, there would not be this difference.

It is true that the adjacent trailing vortices almost cancel -- their strengths are almost equal, so the only part that remains is the difference.  However, the very tip of a wing produces zero lift, so the vorticity distribution trails off to zero there -- so the very tip vortex has very weak strength -- so the fact that it doesn't have a sibling trailing vortex to cancel with isn't super important.

Ah okay, I understand that more now. It makes sense how this would come together to change the lift distribution. Thanks.
